Magnetic field in a tape
This is a theoretical question.
Let's guess we have an unknown magnetic tape cassette, no brand, no numbers or other signs.
The question is: do tools exist, that are able to analyze the magnetic field of the tape, so a tape reader can be built from scratch?
We don't know anything about how the tape was recorded, nor if it's analogic or digital (well, ok, if this becomes too difficult - I've no idea - we can guess it's digital).
About the mechanics, I guess buiding a motor is much simpler task, so I don't care too much, the most important thing is to understand if it's possible deduce the magnetic encoding.
Please notice, of course, this is not related to decrypting an unknown code, but just being able to read the signal.
EDIT: just for completeness, it's a theoretical question about reading an unknown magnetic field, so "brute forcing" (still in theory) all the tape readers ever built since the human history, until we find a brand and model that works, is not conceptually valid...
EDIT again: I try to be more precise in the concrete question part, since some comments tell it's not clear.
I'm asking if there's a tool, some sort of magnetic probe, that could analyze the magnetic field emitted by a tape, with sufficient precision to understand how the tape was recorded, and so, build a tape reader for that particular tape.
Obviously, if there's a tape, there must've been also a reader, that we haven't.

no ... you have no way to determine if the decoded data is correct

You need to know if there are multiple tracks, if there are you need to match them. You could find a way to oversample the tape and decode it, how you would do that I don't know.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@AndyK magnetic tapes no, but magnetic fields yes, I guess? - Because I don't know which one could read that tape - I mean do tools exist to read any magnetic field configuration - A tape reader needs a motor - Brute forcing means finding the correct tape reader by trying the existing ones one by one

Food for thought once the physical layer issue has been solved: https://github.com/oyvindln/vhs-decode

Can we at least see a photo of the cassette? If it is a standard audio cassette, then there are many readers available. Just use Google.

I think the first thing to do is to check if it's a standard size tape and try reading it with existing equipment. Try reading it with a reel-to-reel tape machine with multi-channel (stereo or there may have been quadraphonic ones even?) heads, record the audio it emits, and start looking at that. Remember that some channels might be reversed from others, and the speed will almost certainly be wrong. If the tape has fewer channels than the player, you'd have duplicate channels, but if it has more, you might get some mix of several channels on each channel, which still tells you something.

If the data is digital, it'd be easy to identify mixed channels, as you'd see three or more distinct levels in the output (digital magnetic tape, as far as I'm aware, has never used more than two polarizations, one bit per zone--though I could be wrong about that). Detecting mixed channels in the analog case is harder; if it's audio, you might be able to tell by just listening to it, but if it isn't audio but some other analog data it'd be hard to tell. I'm not sure how you might distinguish things that way.

Of course, there's also the possibility that it could be a helical-scan tape, which would complicate matters. In that case, you'd have to try it with at least a couple of different helical-scan machines--try a VHS mechanism and a betamax mechanism and maybe a umatic mechanism if you can get ahold of one to try it on. If it's none of those, you're probably looking at an MFM like Solomon Slow's answer suggests.


I'm asking if there's a tool, some sort of magnetic probe, that could analyze the magnetic field emitted by a tape, with sufficient precision to understand how the tape was recorded,

It's called a magnetic force microscope, and I imagine it would give you all of the information you'd need to construct a physical mechanism to read the tape.  Understanding how the information is encoded in those magnetic fields is a whole 'nother problem though.
Odd thought: I suppose, you could just use the MFM to scan the whole tape, and get the information straight from the images, but it might take a while.

What if, on the other hand, your budget doesn't allow for time on somebody's MFM? I seem to recall an episode from my youth: Flipping through the pages of some educational products catalog (Edmund Scientific* maybe?) I saw an ad for a tiny phial of some magic liquid that you could paint onto a strip of magnetic tape, and it supposedly would make the magnetization visible to your naked eye. I don't know at what level of detail, but at least it should let you see where the tracks are...
...assuming that some similar product exists today, which, I wouldn't even know what to call it in a Google search.

* Now re-branded as Edmund Optical, with all of the fun, educational stuff gone from the catalog.

There are also "magnetic viewing film" products on Amazon. I don't know if their resolution would be high enough to see features on a recording tape, though. With the fluid, you could paint it on the tape, let it dry and then lift it off with a piece of scotch tape to get a high-resolution pattern you could examine under a microscope.

@DaveTweed, I got my hands on a piece of that stuff one time. It needs a pretty strong field to make it change color, and it's got some thickness to it, as if the active substance is laminated between layers of plastic. I'd bet that it won't work, but if OP wants to bet the other way, it'll only cost them a few dollars.
